# Python list comprehension - simple

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list and I want to use a certain function only on those entries of it that fulfills a certain condition - leaving the other entries unmodified.

Example: Say I want to multiply by 2 only those elements who are even.

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Wanted result:

```
a_list => [1, 4, 3, 8, 5]
```

But `[elem * 2 for elem in a_list if elem %2 == 0]` yields `[4, 8]` (it acted as a filter in addition).

What is the correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions):

```
[x * 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x
 for x in a_list]
```

(Math geek's note: you can also solve this particular case with

```
[x * (2 - x % 2) for x in a_list]
```

but I'd prefer the first option anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.
Also, thanks for the edits, I'll try to use the same format next.

Answer (score 2):

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print [elem*2 if elem%2==0 else elem  for elem in a_list ]
```

or, if you have a very long list that you want to modify in place:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i,elem in enumerate(a_list):
    if elem%2==0:
        a_list[i] = elem*2
```

so, only the even elements are modified

Comment: Shouldn't `a_list[:] = list_comprehension` work too for in-place replacement? And that without having to loop in python?

Comment: @agf So it'd create the new list somewhere else and then afterwards update the elements? Too bad, I thought because of the limitations of the list comprehensions we could guarantee that an element may only be referenced before it was overwritten so that could be optimized.

Comment: @Voo In-place assignment works from any iterable, so you could do it from a generator expression instead. I just tried it, and that actually seems to work even if you use `reversed(a_list)` or a generator that yields less items than the length of the list. Not something I've thought of doing before; thanks for bringing up the idea :).

Comment: @agf Yeah I know, but I thought we could special case something like list comprehensions - a shorter list isn't problematic as we'd just have to set the size variable afterwards, but I assume it's not important enough (and who knows about downfalls). But if it works with a generator, that's good enough for most cases - thanks for testing and sharing the results :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> f = lambda x: x%2 and x or x*2
>>> a_list = [f(i) for i in a_list]
>>> a_list
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5]
```

**Edit** - Thinking about [agf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500584/agf)'s remark I made a 2nd version of my code:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> f = lambda x: x if x%2 else x*2
>>> a_list = [f(i) for i in a_list]
>>> a_list
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5]
```

Comment: Don't use `condition and true_value or false_value` to emulate the ternary operation; there is a really version in Python. Also, there is no need to wrap it in a lambda either way, as it is an expression rather than a statement it works fine right in the list comprehension. `lambda`s have the same limitation, so there is _never_ a need for one in a list comprehension or generator expression.

Comment: @agf - I understand (and agree with) your comment about lambda, but in this case it seems to me an alternative way (although far away from be absolutely perfect) to put on different levels the logic of selecting items from the list comprehension.
And thank you for the remainder about Python ternary operator. I made a 2nd version to reflect this.

Comment: `lambda x:` and `f()` is 12 characters, `[ for i in a_list]` is 18 -- so you're making it clearer and faster by having the expression inline rather than in a `lambda` for only six more characters if you have a whole separate list comprehension instead of just a new function.